# Maya MEL save listAttr into array

Tags: maya, mel

Cheers,
I am writing on a tool that should get all attributes with a specific prefix and save them into an array.

When I use the listAttr on its own it gives me something like this:
`// Result: message caching isHistoricallyInteresting nodeState...`

My problem: I want to save the list of the Attribute with a specific prefix into an array

mel code:

```
string $currentSelection[] = `ls -sl`;
string $currentAttributes[];            
$currentShapeNode = `ls -shapes -dag -sl $currentSelection`;
string $currentAttributes[] = `listAttr -ct "ai*"`;
print $currentAttributes;
```

The `$currentAttributes`list stays empty. I can´t figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably confused with category and string. If you take a look close in doc

ct ->   only show attributes belonging to the given category. Category string can be a regular expression.

st ->   List only the attributes that match the other criteria AND match the string(s) passed from this flag. String can be a regular expression.

So in your case you probably looking for st

This works

```
string $currentSelection[] = `ls -sl`;
string $currentAttributes[];            
$currentShapeNode = `ls -shapes -dag -sl $currentSelection`;
string $currentAttributes[] = `listAttr -st "ai*"`;
print $currentAttributes;
```